# gnome 3 system sounds not working

Tags: debian, audio, gnome3, testing

On my System (Debian Wheezy x64, Gnome 3) I don't have any system sounds. Other audio is working well.

When I go to settings > Audio > Sounds (hope it is called like this in english) as normal user, all sounds are greyed out. However, when i go to this panel as root, I can play all these sounds.

Is it a problem with privileges?

How can it be solved?  I will need notifications in Empathy.

Comment: check whether your non-root user is in audio group

Comment: thank you! I've checked that before: here is the output of groups:
`#groups:
marcel adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games avahi-autoipd avahi netdev bluetooth lpadmin fuse vboxusers pulse-access`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=75040).

What you need to to is fire up **d**conf-editor

Go to *org/gnome/desktop/sound* and there activate *event_sounds* after a restart empathy notification sounds should be working !